# Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) when conducting for loop for cointegration test in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I was using for loop in R to conduct adf.test for four series(I expected there would be 16=4X4 adf.test outputs).
But it returned an error: Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula.Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

#Here is my data frame which including four series:

```
CE_price
 Sonos.Inc GoPro..Inc. Hamilton.Beach.Brands.Holding.Co UNIVERSAL.ELECTRONICS.INC
1  13.48714    4.110586                         14.94600                  44.99887
2  13.22786    4.040829                         15.08333                  44.04571
3  13.83207    4.066529                         15.09615                  45.65071
4  13.75500    4.022857                         15.13800                  42.13223
5  13.17276    3.948729                         14.96821                  42.13223
6  12.18420    3.813100                         14.44910                  42.13223
```

#Here is my code:

```
require(tseries)
for (i in 1:ncol(CE_price)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(CE_price)){
  col_i<-colnames(CE_price)[i]
  col_j<-colnames(CE_price)[j]
  comb_i_j<-lm(CE_price[,i],CE_price[,j])
  coin_i_j<-adf.test(comb_i_j$residuals,k=1)
  print(paste(col_i,'&',col_j,'coin_result is',coin_i_j ))
  }}
```

Return: Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you want to fit a model with CE_price[,i] as dependent variable.

So you replace the comma with a tilde (~). The first (and in this case, only) argument to tilde is a formula, not the dependent variable.

comb_i_j<-lm(CE_price[,i]~CE_price[,j])

Comment: The code is correct right now after replacing the comma with a tilde(~). Thanks!